# Why the navigation header is hidden in ios13?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

When i add with PushViewController the navigation  header  remains visible with this code:

```
View viewp = new View();
NavigationController.PushViewController(viewp, false);
```

but when i add with PresentViewControllerAsync the navigation header is hidden, what is wrong?

```
viewp.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FullScreen;
this.PresentViewController(viewp, true, null);
```

i am using ios13, what is my wrong? **the buttons right and left do not show**

[image]

Comment: You can share two screenshots to show difference between them , this will be helpful to know whether it's an issue in iOS 13 .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT the buttons right and left do not show

Comment: Okey ,thanks for updating question .If the buttons right and left is in Navigation bar , when using `PresentViewController` then it will not show .Have a look at my answer .

Comment: If answer be helpful , remember to mark ot vote up later when have time.Thanks in advance *.^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with them , it's a normal phenomenon .

- **PushViewController** need Root View Controller is `NavigationController` , it only can be used in NavigationController .Therefore , when invoking need as follow :

  NavigationController.PushViewController(xxx)

That also is the reason can see Navigation Bar by this method. Next page is under Navigation Controller . Have a look at [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller?language=objc) and [pushViewController:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621887-pushviewcontroller?language=objc) defined :

[image]

- However ,  **[PresentViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/gkdialogcontroller/1520909-presentviewcontroller?language=occ)** can be invoked no matter root view controller wherther be NavigationController or Other controller . It just presents a view controller in the dialog controller’s window. Then there will not show navigation bar in next view , because it's not under the stack of Navigation Controller Stack.

[image]

Here are some good discussion about difference between them for reference.

[Difference between pushViewController and showViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28498947/difference-between-pushviewcontroller-and-showviewcontroller/28499020)

[difference between presentViewController and UINavigationController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233017/difference-between-presentviewcontroller-and-uinavigationcontroller)